# Firestore Matching App showing users only once

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i am building a matching app like Tinder with Flutter and Firestore.

To show other users in the feed, I am using this method:

```
Future<FirebasePaginatedResult<UserEntity>> getFeed({
    int limit = 20,
    DocumentSnapshot? lastDocument,
  }) async {
    var query = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').withConverter<UserEntity>(
    fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => UserEntity.fromDoc(snapshot)!,
    toFirestore: (data, _) => data.toJson(),
  ).limit(limit);

    if (lastDocument != null) {
      query = query.startAfterDocument(lastDocument);
    }

    var snapshot = await query.get();
    var users = snapshot.docs.map((e) => e.data()).toList();

    return FirebasePaginatedResult(
      data: users,
      hasMore: users.length == limit,
      lastDocument: snapshot.docs.lastOrNull,
    );
  }
```

It works fine to get a paginated feed of users. Now, if I open the app, swipe through a few users, close the app and open it again, I would see the same users that I've just swiped through. That's not what I want. I want to see every user only once, and when I swiped them, I don't want to see them again.

What I tried is just saving all the userIds that I have swiped and then adding this line:

```
query = query.where('uid', whereNotIn: usersToIgnore);
```

But whereNotIn seems to have a limit of 10, so it doesn't work for my case.

I could also just sort out all the swiped users after fetching them from firestore, but I don't like that idea because it wouldn't work so well with the pagination, plus I would make a lot of unnecessary requests. E.g. I have already swiped through 200 users -> Everytime I want to fetch the feed again, I would have to fetch those 200 users from firestore only to sort them out anyways, this would cause a lot of read requests.

Any other ideas how to build that?

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure if i get you correctely so take a look below:

```
Future<FirebasePaginatedResult<UserEntity>> getFeed({
  int limit = 20,
  DocumentSnapshot? lastDocument,
   //below pass the list of users to be ignored
  List<String> usersToIgnore = const [],
}) async {
  var query = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Users')
      .withConverter<UserEntity>(
        fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => UserEntity.fromDoc(snapshot)!,
        toFirestore: (data, _) => data.toJson(),
      )
      .limit(limit);

  if (lastDocument != null) {
    query = query.startAfterDocument(lastDocument);
  }

  var snapshot = await query.get();
  var users = snapshot.docs.map((e) => e.data()).toList();

  // filter the users to ignore
  users = users.where((user) => !usersToIgnore.contains(user.uid)).toList();

  return FirebasePaginatedResult(
    data: users,
    hasMore: users.length == limit,
    lastDocument: snapshot.docs.lastOrNull,
  );
}
```

Comment: This technically works, but it is exactly what I described in the last paragraph. I would have to read every user that I have already swiped until I get to the ones that I haven't swiped yet. If I do this everytime, I will end up with a ton of read operations.

Comment: so far with this data str. i don't think you can do any more cost efficient solution.